# Difference of the two versions of partition used in quicksort

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, quicksort, partition

The first one is straightforward, just walk from both sides until finding a reversion.

```
/*C++ version, [first, last), last needs --first to fetch the last element*/
/*returns the middle of partitioning result*/
int* partition( int *first, int *last, int pivot ) {
    while (true) {
        while (*first < pivot) ++first;
        --last;//Don't edit this, it's true.
        while (pivot < *last) --last;
        if (!(first < last)) return first;
        swap(*first, *last);
        ++first;
    }
}
```

The second one (shown in "*Introduction to algorithms*") is:

```
int* partition( int a[], int n, int pivot ) {
    bound = 0;
    for ( i = 1; i != n; ++i )
        if ( a[i] < pivot )
            swap( &a[i], &a[++bound]);
    swap(a, a + bound);
    return a + bound;
}
```

The invariant of the second one is " **All elements before bound is less than pivot** " .

**Q: And what is the advantages and disadvantages of the two versions?**

I'll give one first, the second one require ++ operation on the iterator( pointer ), so it can be applied to some `ForwardIterator` like the iterator of a linked list. Other tips?

Comment: Is the first one actually correct, isn't the `--last` on the third line in the wrong place?

Comment: @Joni No, this is a c++ version in which last is an iterator that is one pass the last element.

Comment: In that case I would recommend giving the full implementation,  including the function definition and declarations for `first`, `last` and `pivot`, and a specification of what the function is supposed to return (the first one has a return statement, the second doesn't)

Comment: The first is the common algorithm used for finding *two* elements that are on wrong (opposite) sides of the pivot slot, and swapping them. The second is designed to choose where the pivot slot will eventually be, adjusting it incrementally and moving all values less than the pivot *value* below it in the process. Of the two, the second is usually easier to understand by beginners and imho less prone to erroneous implementations. The second can trigger more swaps, but both have similar complexity.

Comment: @Joni Fine, done. Sorry for my vague statement.

Comment: @WhozCraig And your comments make remind me that the second one is `online`. Another difference!

Comment: @zoujyjs Both algorithms are explained fairly well on the wiki page for quick-sort. When i code the algorithm, I prefer the latter, Either work fine. The heart of quicksort is choosing a pivot, and a *random* pivot choice is essential to reduce chance of a polarized worst-case runtime. Hopefully the explanation, however, made sense.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm sorry, I don't understand how the first one has got a fixed pivot slot. Do you mind explaining the statement??

Comment: @WhozCraig The invariant is [0,first) is all <= pivot, and (last, back] is all >= pivot. And you keep swapping the reversions that violate this invariant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the basic idea of the two algorithms go, both are correct. They will do the same number of comparisons but the second one will do more swaps than the first.

You can see this by stepping through the algorithms as they partition the array `1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6 5` using 5 as the pivot. When the first algorithm swaps two numbers it never touches either of then again. The second algorithm first swaps 9 and 2, then 9 and 3, and so on, taking multiple swaps to move 9 to its final position.

There are other differences too. If I haven't made any mistakes, this is how the first algorithm partitions the array:

```
1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6 5
f                 l
1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6 5  # swap 9,5
  f             l
1 5 2 8 3 7 4 6 9  # swap 8,4
      f     l
1 5 2 4 3 7 8 6 9  # return f = 5
        l f
```

This is how the second algorithm partitions the array:

```
1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6 5  # 1<5, swap 1,1
bi      
1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6 5  # 9>5, no swap
  bi
1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6 5  # 2<5, swap 9,2
  b i
1 2 9 8 3 7 4 6 5  # 8>5, no swap
    b i
1 2 9 8 3 7 4 6 5  # 3<5, swap 9,3
    b   i
1 2 3 8 9 7 4 6 5  # 7>5, no swap
      b   i
1 2 3 8 9 7 4 6 5  # 4<5, swap 8,4
      b     i
1 2 3 4 9 7 8 6 5  # 6>5, no swap
        b     i
1 2 3 4 9 7 8 6 5  # 5=5, exit loop, swap 9,5
        b       i
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 6 9  # return b = 4
        b       i
```

Notice how it makes 5 swaps, compared to just 2 of the other algorithm. It also moves the last item in the array to the middle array. In this case the last item happens to be the pivot so it's the pivot that's moved to the middle, but that's not the general case.

Comment: This is pretty good. The second example there is reason behind the last swap. Normally a pivot index `x` is chosen at the start, then `swap(a[x],a[len-1])` is done to "store" the pivot value in the last location. The test condition of the loop is normally `if ( a[i] < a[len-1] )` because that is where the pivot "value" is kept. And `a[bound]` will always be where the pivot value needs to go after the loop is finished, moving it there with one final swap. The same algorithm can also be done top-to-bottom, keeping the pivot value in `a[0]` until the loop finishes and the final swap occurs.

Comment: A sample of the second implemented as an iterator-based template can be seen here: [See It Live](http://ideone.com/8Izjmv). Nice writeup (+1)

Comment: @WhozCraig As a convention, the template parameters should named ForwardIterator which indicates the lowest requirement of the iterator. It's non the less a nice one, but STL do a lot more optimazations including eliminating the tail recursion, limit the depth of recursion, using a heapsort or insertion sort at a certain threshold, which is called introsort (*D. R. Musser, "Introspective Sorting and Selection Algorithms", Software Practice and Experience 27(8):983, 1997.*). For more details, refer to http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html

Comment: @zoujyjs surely. Some of the implementations of `std::sort` are outright *amazing*. The one for my implementation, the LLVM implementation from MIT) is simply outstanding. The steps they've gone to for smaller partition sorting are the result of a *lot* of work, and do exactly as you describe. They even go the extra mile for inlined 2,3,4, and 5 element unrolls. Beyond that up to a configurable limit it is insertion-sort, including temporary partial sorts, etc. Its like reading a science journal on sorting algorithms.

Comment: @WhozCraig Isn't it nicer if the second recursion is written as `quicksort(++pvt, last)`, `pvt+1` require the iterator be a `RandomAccessIterator` since it use a `operator+`.

Comment: @zoujyjs Probably. been a long time since I even analyzed that code, so I'll take it  you're correct.

Comment: @WhozCraig And why `Iterator pvt = std::next(first, (std::rand() % (len-1)));` instead of `rand() % len`? So many questions :).

Comment: @zoujyjs Now *that* is a good question. The algorithm is supposed to use the last slot for the pivot storage, but in the process that rand-pick should not discount that slot as the potential pick. It would definitely slightly reduce the random pick by excluding that slot. I'm going to change both of those issues. Thanks for bringing them to my attention.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37808/discussion-between-zoujyjs-and-whozcraig)